# twiiter bootstrap align thumbnails dynamically

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i'd like to have the thumbnails aligned dynamically, but how can i do it?

i have the following code:

HTML

```
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <ul class="thumbnails">

         <uc1:loadUsers runat="server" ID="loadUsers" />

        </ul>
      </div>
```

ASP.NET

this is a UserControl

_str is a string which will be added to a literal control which converts this to HTML

```
                    _str =  "<li class='span3'>"
                        + "<div class='thumbnail'>"
                        + "<div class='caption'>"

                        + "<h3>" + _name + "</h3>"
                        + "<ul>"
                        + "<li><h5>" + _other + "</h5></li>"
                        + "<li><h5>" + _other + "</h5></li>"
                        + "<li><h5><img src='" + _imagePath + "'" + _size + " /> " + _other + "</h5></li>"
                        + "<br><li>"
                        + "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-info'>Options</button><button class='btn btn-info dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><span class='caret'></span></button><ul class='dropdown-menu'>"
                        + "<li><a href='users.aspx?delete=" + _id + "'><i class='icon-fire'></i> Delete</a></li>"
                        + "<li><a href='users.aspx?edit=" + _id + "'><i class='icon-edit'></i> Edit</a></li>"
                        + "</ul></div>"
                        + "</li>"
                        + "</ul>"

                        + "</div>"
                        + "</div>"
                        + "</li>";
```

i know that the class='row-fluid' is the responsible for the alignment, how can i use it dinamicly?

[image: as you can see the thumbnails aren't aligned and i want them to stay perfectly aligned]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by aligning it dynamically. Can you provide a screenshot on what's going on? Dynamically meaning run-time or dynamic in terms of change in window size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i was inserting `<li>` but in HTML i didn't have an `<ul>`, thats the reason to this to be unformulated dynamically. 
So i've inserted `<div></div>` at the beginning and in the end of the dynamic control.

i solved this easily:

```
_str =  "<div><li class='span3'>"
                    + "<div class='thumbnail'>"
                    + "<div class='caption'>"

                    + "<h3>" + _name + "</h3>"
                    + "<ul>"
                    + "<li><h5>" + _other + "</h5></li>"
                    + "<li><h5>" + _other + "</h5></li>"
                    + "<li><h5><img src='" + _imagePath + "'" + _size + " /> " + _other + "</h5></li>"
                    + "<br><li>"
                    + "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-info'>Options</button><button class='btn btn-info dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><span class='caret'></span></button><ul class='dropdown-menu'>"
                    + "<li><a href='users.aspx?delete=" + _id + "'><i class='icon-fire'></i> Delete</a></li>"
                    + "<li><a href='users.aspx?edit=" + _id + "'><i class='icon-edit'></i> Edit</a></li>"
                    + "</ul></div>"
                    + "</li>"
                    + "</ul>"

                    + "</div>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "</li></div>";
```